# How to start a local web-server on windows?

Tags: web-services

So recently I switched from Linux to Windows (I regret it alot) - of course for school - and I have a project, but I need to start a local webserver. I can do this on linux, with Samba, but on windows i have no idea how to do it.

Also, how can I do it with Admin. I have admin on my computer.

Thanks,

Artificial Engineer

Comment: I never heard of samba being used to create a web server. Sounds like you're just looking for file sharing or printer sharing.

Comment: Oh sorry, apache2, Thants what i meant